# Why are my Questions and Scores updating incorrectly in a JSON based game

Tags: javascript, json

So i've built out a small scale jeopardy game, and it all works except for my function that handles the answer (if an answer us submitted).

## **What I want to happen**

When you submit an answer, the question should remove the class `unanswered` and gain add the corresponding value to the `score` variable.

## **What it's currently doing**

Upon submitting an answer, the class `unanswered` stays present(Allowing users to click a question they have answered beforehand). The score update does work*

- Except that it takes the first value and applies 100pts to each question, so out of 3 questions, my max is `300` when it should be `600`.

Since this is a decently sized app, I'll include a plunkr below, but here are my files:

**Handle Answer Function**

```
var category = $(this).parent().data('category');
var value = $(this).data('question');
var score = $('#unanswered').html();
var tempvar = x[category][value];
var answers = $('#answers');    
 
function handleAnswer(){
    $('.answer').click(function(){// hide empty the tile, mike it unclickable, update the score if correct, and hide the modal
        var tile = $('div[data-category="'+$(this).data('category')+'"]>[data-question="'+$(this).data('question')+'"]')[0];
        $(tile).empty().removeClass('unanswered').unbind().css('cursor','not-allowed');
        if ($(this).data('correct')){
            score += parseInt($(this).data('value'));
        }
        $('#question-modal').modal('hide');
        updateScore();
    });
}
```

**[Questions.JSON](http://pastebin.com/4LbhPeH5)**

**[Fully Working PLUNKR Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NpOTINwhOJhmqYNNU8lK?p=preview)**

## **Things I've tried**

To be honest, I've built this out 3 different times trying different pathing routes and I can't seem to get them all working together. I've messed with different variables and entire JSON structuring.

---

Thanks for taking a look, I appreciate any help or direction you can point me to!

Comment: With only what you showed, nothing seems obviously wrong. Please show us involved HTML part.

Comment: @cFreed I'll add it above, but I don't want the question to become too long of format, you can find the HTML in this **[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ivxejRNa8Hk0lJh37JvC?p=preview)** link but I'll also include it in this **[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Gjf2yrGt)**

Comment: Your links don't show any of the HTML part involved by your question. I guess they should reside in the (currently empty in what your links show) `<div id="answers">`, and are probably `.answer` classed elements and their content. Please show at least a template of that.

Comment: @cFreed oops forgot to fork my plunk to public, try this **[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NpOTINwhOJhmqYNNU8lK?p=preview)** link now

Comment: Sorry: your new link only shows "Loading...".

Comment: @cFreed have no idea why it's not showing for you, try this https://embed.plnkr.co/NpOTINwhOJhmqYNNU8lK/

Comment: In your last link, again I see only an _empty_ `<div id="answers" class="text-center">`!

Comment: @cFreed I'm really sorry about these issues, here is a link to the zip if you wish try to run this locally. http://www.filedropper.com/jeopardy

Comment: Looking at `scripts.js` I see that it's here that you create the questions that go inside the `<div id="answers">`. What I noticed is that you seem to have an `id="unanswered"` affected to any question: this is illegal, and might (or not) cause something else to turn wrong.  But I'm not sure of anything (BTW you must realize we don't want to locally run entire projects, but only look at your code and search what's wrong). So again, please post a _full and precise_ sample of the HTML code of a typical question.

Comment: I figured it out, but to be fair; I did post all of the things that relate to S/O. I have the sample code that was the problem and I had the minimal code example on Plunkr. I sent the link to a colleague and he was able to see it fine. @cFreed